# Android: How to change font style for Hebrew text?

Tags: android, xml, fonts, styles, hebrew

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. I am fairly new to android, and I am trying to change the Hebrew text font in my application to a more biblical look. Any ideas? A tutorial would be greatly appreciated.